# Get facebook login popup every time user try to Login using facebook from my website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to implement Facebook login on my website as part of authentication and using Facebook JavaScript SDK for that.

used a simple code as

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', //change the appId to your appId
    status: true, 
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true});

function updateButton(response) 
{       
    if (response.status === 'connected') 
    {
        $('#fb-auth').on('click',function(){
            FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                login(response, info);
            });


            //FB.logout(function(response) {
                //logout(response);
            //});
        });
    }
    else 
    {
        $('#fb-auth').on('click',function(){
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                        login(response, info);
                    });    
                } 
                else {
                    ;
                }
            }, {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me'});   
        });
    }
}
FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
//FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);  
};
```

Facebook login works fine but what I am trying to do is when next time they try Login with Facebook , they should get login pop-up and option to login as another user.

After first login , next time when they are trying to login with facebook again and they are logged into facebook in another tab its just redirecting them to logged in page without any pop-up or anything.

Can anyone please give me some pointer as what need to be done to achieve that.

Comment: But...the user is already logged in.. Are you trying to allow the user to log in as a different user? In that case, you'll want to redirect your users to a log-off procedure first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to login the user everytime he visits the app, you should implement [**FB.logout**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/), when you get the status as `connected` on `getLoginStatus()` when the app starts.

So the session when be destroyed and then you can call `FB.login` again. Just like-

```
// app starts here
FB.getLoginStatus()
{
    if(status == "connected")

        // call FB.logout()
        // call FB.login()

    else

        // call FB.login()

 }
```

Comment: Thanks , Yes that was the issue. I was not using logout properly.
Actually was not using Facebook Logout at all and because of that it was not getting logged off from facebook.